# clear jEdit cache?

Tags: macos, command-line, crash, java

I've been using jEdit for years on Mac

Recently I believe it crashed, or something must have happened, and it cannot start since then. I've been using jar installed file before, now I came across this topic : [How to help the jEdit application find java?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/426713/how-to-help-the-jedit-application-find-java)
and almost make it work... but it reaches the same point as .jar installation

It seems there is some cache that is not cleared neither with app nor by java reinstall. (I tried a couple of times).

What I can see is

```
12:51:36 PM [AWT-EventQueue-0] [warning] View: Buffer  DI 14SU2 9443 defect/log63.log doesn't exist
12:51:36 PM [AWT-EventQueue-0] [warning] View: Buffer  DI 14SU2 9443 defect/SEP64D989C24B5E.cnf.xml doesn't exist
12:51:36 PM [AWT-EventQueue-0] [error] AWT-EventQueue-0: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
12:51:36 PM [AWT-EventQueue-0] [error] AWT-EventQueue-0: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.gjt.sp.jedit.Buffer (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.gjt.sp.jedit.Buffer is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

"DI 14SU2 9443 defect/" is partial name of folder where I have/had logs I analyzed.
Removing, recreating this folder or files do not help. It always crashes after same line..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it

```
    /Users/username/Library/jEdit/perspective.xml
```

this file contained opened files, and removing it helped